# How does the rendering engine perceive the resource type? Is there a documentation that explains the process?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, puppeteer

I have been downloading resources like XHR, CSS, HTML, and JavaScript using puppeteer but would like to know what is the process behind it. When I checked the puppeteer documentation, it says the following for `request.resourceType()`:

> Contains the request's resource type as it was perceived by the rendering engine.

I would like to know how the rendering engine classifies them. Is it based on the *content-type* or *request headers*?

This question was raised because when I checked for https://google.com in the Chrome DevTools, the main HTML is displayed as `document` whereas other documents with type `text/html` are classified as `other`.

But this is correctly classified as `HTML` in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the corresponding source code in the Chromium source code [here](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/e1508c61f10785ea9737954903f2b46e98c88f2d/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/har_importer/HARImporter.js#L145).

The process is the following:

**Step 1**: Chrome tries to identify by using the mime type

This will identify the following resource types ([source code](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/5e228392e2b5ea67e50c91b629c45e069d24b93f/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/common/ResourceType.js#L51)):

- `document` for `text/html`
- `stylesheet` for `text/css`
- `image` for `image/...`
- `script` for `text/...` (exluding documents) or mime types containing `script`
- `font` if mime type includes `font`

**Step 2**: If that does not work, Chrome tries to identify the resource type by using the URL/file extension

Examples, what will be identified ([source code](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/5e228392e2b5ea67e50c91b629c45e069d24b93f/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/common/ResourceType.js#L77)):

- `script` for `js`
- `stylesheet` for `css`
- `image` for `jpeg`, `gif`, `tiff`
- See [this code](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/5e228392e2b5ea67e50c91b629c45e069d24b93f/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/common/ResourceType.js#L264) for the full list

**Step 3**: If that also does not work, `other` will be the resource type

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thomas.